# VB Access database Preventing Duplicate Entries error

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, duplicates

`sqlLink.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='C:\Users\will\Documents\Computing\ComputingProjectDatabase.accdb';"
        sqlLink.Open()
        Try
            If txtUsername.Text = "" Then
                MsgBox("You did not enter a Username!")
                Return
            ElseIf txtPassword.Text = "" Then
                MsgBox("You did not enter a Password!")
                Return
            ElseIf txtPassword.Text <> txtPasswordConf.Text Then
                MsgBox("Your passwords do not match!")
                Return
            Else`

```
            Using sqlOrder As New OleDbCommand
                Dim sqlCheck As New OleDbCommand
                sqlCheck.CommandText = "SELECT count(*) FROM LoginSystem WHERE username = @username"
                sqlCheck.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtUsername.Text)

                Dim oleRdr As OleDbDataReader
                oleRdr = sqlCheck.ExecuteReader()
                If oleRdr.HasRows = True Then
                    oleRdr.Read()
                    If oleRdr.Item(0) = 0 Then
                        sqlOrder.CommandText = "INSERT INTO LoginSystem ([Username], [Password], [PasswordConf]) VALUES ('" & txtUsername.Text & "','" & txtPassword.Text & "','" & txtPasswordConf.Text & "')"
                        sqlOrder.ExecuteNonQuery()
                        MsgBox("You have successfully registered, you can log in now!")
                    Else
                        MsgBox("Username is not currently available, please choose new username.")
                    End If
                End If
            End Using

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("An error occurred:" & ex.Message)

    End Try
    sqlLink.Close()
    Me.Close()
    LoginScreen.Show()
End Sub
```

Hey again >.< only a little question here. Every time I create a duplicate copy of a set of Login Data (in this case the username is Heather and password is Trentshop) I am returned with an awkward "Data has been saved" and then a long error stating the data was not saved as there is already a duplicate of it available.

Ideally I would prefer it to just say "Username is already in use, please choose a new one". I've fiddled around with ExceptDuplicateName and other similar types. But for some reason can't get my head around this. I think I'm missing something really obvious, in which case it would be a great help if anyone can help me solve this issue >.<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to handle this is to probably check before you try and insert that the username is available.You should also be using parameterised queries as a tool against sql injection.

```
Dim sqlCheck As New OleDbCommand
sqlCheck.CommandText = "SELECT count(*) FROM LoginSystem WHERE username = @username"
sqlCheck.Connection = sqlLink
sqlCheck.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username",txtUsername.Text)

Dim oleRdr as new OleDbReader = sqlCheck.ExecuteReader()
If oleRdr.HasRows = True Then
    oleRdr.Read()
    If oleRdr.Item(0) = 0 Then
        'username is available and you can do insert command now
    Else
        'username is not available
    End If
End If
```

You should also use the 'using' statement to correctly dispose of your objects where appropriate, but since this is tangent to your question i'll just provide a link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx

Or you could create a stored procedure to handle this whole process which returns a value to indicate success or failure

Comment: I integrated this into the code, and it looks like it should work, however I'm getting a "Connection not established error from it", not entirely sure, never really experienced it before. Very odd.

Comment: you probably need to use the .Open() method on your connection object before you can execute the reader

Comment: and you need to set the connection property of your oledbcommands:
sqlCheck.Connection = sqlLink

Comment: awesome, the sqlCheck.connection = sqlLink worked perfectly, thx man